# Max between a list and an int

Tags: python, list, max

I have a list which I need all elements to be compared with an int and then return a list.

For example:

`mylist = [1, 5, -2, 7]`

something like this:

`max(mylist, 0) => [1, 5, 0, 7]`

How should I do that?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You need to do `max` one element at a time, e.g. `[max(el, 0) for el in mylist]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
num = 0
mylist = [1, 5, -2, 7]
ans = [e if e>=num else num for e in mylist]
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 0, 7]
```

Comment: Yes. Actually I am wondering if there is any predefined function instead of using a loop.

Comment: You could also do `[max(e, num) for e in mylist]` but I don't see a way to avoid iterating over `mylist`.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks PApostol

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, please select it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The `If` statement is cheaper than the `max()` built-in function, although the code @PApostol mentioned is more readable. Thanks to both guys.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list by

- iterating over the orignal

  - make the comparison with the int
  - *keep* the value that meets the criteria

Answer (score 0):

NumPy [library](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) with the power of SIMD instructions provides that.
Generally, if you have a `list` or `array` called `a`:

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([1, -2, 3, 4, 5, -6, -7, -8, 9])
```

> note using a NumPy array instead of a `list` makes the computation much
> faster, faster than any `for loop`. Vice versa using NumPy for `list`s
> is not efficient as a `for loop`.

```
np.maximum(0, a)
```

Output:

```
[1 0 3 4 5 0 0 0 9]
```